# Why does Child Class shaddow Parent methods even though parameters are of different type

Tags: c++, oop

My parent class holds two functions: On is supposed to be overwritten by the child, the second (same name) just uses as input a different type and than uses the overwritten method. Now I understand that if I define in the child class a method with the **same name and same input parameters**, it will shadow (is that the right expression?) the parents method. But I can still call the parents method by calling it explicit like: `b.A::getSize(...)`.

My question is: Why does the parent method get shadowed even if the input parameter types are **different**? Why can't the compiler find the parent method with the correct input types? See the below minimal example.

And bonus question: Is it possible to achieve the behaviour that I can call the parents method without the need of the explicit call and without modifying `main(){...}` nor `class B{...};` nor using different names?

```
#include <cstdio>

class A{
    public:
    virtual void getSize(size_t &i) = 0;

    void getSize(int &d){
        size_t i;
        getSize(i);
        d = static_cast<int>(i);
    }
};

class B : public A{
    public:
    void getSize(size_t &i) override{
        i = 4;
    }
};

int main(){
    size_t t;
    int i;
    B b;
    b.getSize(t);
    b.getSize(i); // error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'int'
    b.A::getSize(i); // this works but is not acceptable (too much changes in production code)
    printf("%zu, %d",t,i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to make the parent method visible in the inherited classes interface, you should use a using statement to expose it `using A::getSize;`.

Comment: hmm Sorry that doesn't help. As I sad: I don't want to change the main (in this minimal working example its simple but) I don't want to change (add ```using A::getSize()```) in about 100 different legacy (old) code functions). The infinit loop is my mistake.. that is correct. ```int i``` should be ```size_t i``` I corrected that, thanks.

Comment: @Jakobimatrix: No, you don't put `using A::getSize()` in all the functions that need it. You put it in `B`.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica:
This is actually an acceptable solution... First I was afraid, since there were a lot of child classes, but only a handful have problems (which is lucky but I take it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to expose the method with a using statement:

```
class B : public A
{
    // ...
    using A::getSize;
}
```

---

In your code snippets, you have used uninitialised values in many places, this invokes UB.